# powershell console : any way to recall a command from keyboard shortcut?

Tags: powershell, console, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can use <kbd>F7</kbd> to display command history and I can search the history to find a command that I've typed before ( like for example :)

```
Get-History |select -expand commandline |sls proc
```

but I wonder if the is a way to use a keybord shortcut to cycle through the history (like  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does on linux console) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab completion supports searching through memory, you could type:

```
#proc<TAB>
```

to cycle through commands that match the string 'proc'.  But if you're looking for a more bash like editing experience, then you want PSReadline - https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine.

Comment: tab will not complete against *history*, PSReadline seems promising, I will take a look thanks

Comment: tab will complete against history if the command line is a comment (starts with '#').  It does string matching, or if it's a number, it will complete to that numbered item in history.

Comment: @Kayasax PSReadline is *definitely* worth trying out.  I think you'll love it.  Import the module and just try out Ctrl+a,Ctrl+c which copies the entire command line to clipboard - awesomeness.  Or user Ctrl+v to paste clipboard text onto the command line. And there's lots, lots more capability.

Comment: @JasonShirk didnt know these Nice!

Comment: @JasonShirk can I use your module on my windows7 station ? WMF5 is not available on that system.

Comment: Yes, but you'll need PowerShell V3 or greater.